# .carto file extension is not allowed in CARTO

Tags: carto

I want to import a .carto file but I get the following error message: `unfortunately this file extension is not allowed`.

[image]

I didn't make this file. Do you know if there is any tool that would help me understand what's the problem with it? Unless it's a problem from CARTO as they say they don't recognize there own file extension.

I have a trial subscription.

## Update

I tried [BeaR's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343078/152348): to zip it. It was uploading, it lead me to the layer dashboard before giving me a new error ...

[image]

It doesn't seem to be a new issue as [they already talked about it in Github in 2017](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/11334). I don't know if the answer was solved but even when renaming my file with only lowercase I wasn't able to load it.

Answer (score 1):

In Builder, you can add new layers from your local folders (or from your CARTO account). In the dashboard, you can also add new datasets from your local folders. These could be used then as layers in Builder.

But if you want to import a map, **you would need to drag and drop the .carto onto your dashboard**. This zip file contains a json file with all your map properties (widgets, styles...) and a geopackage for each of your layers/datasets.

[image: drag-and-drop-carto-file]

Answer (score 0):

You must zip the file and upload it in that way.

[image]

I hope it works

Comment: I just tried. It was uploaded, it lead me to the layer dashboard before giving me a new error ...

Comment: Maybe it is because of the name, I recommend you avoid _ character, write a simple name.

Comment: I just tried with `test.zip` and it returns: `Error connecting test.zip`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Zipping the .carto file and removing _ from the name didn't work. I uploaded the .carto files to my google storage bucket, made them public, and then used the link uploader option (on the right): 
[image]

It then uploaded the .carto file as a layer just fine.